# Get Checkbox value from the database into a table row (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

This may be a simple question but I am new to MVC. So please bear with me.

I want to get the checkbox value into the table row. Here is my code for the table.

```
<tbody>
  @foreach (var itms in Model.takeoverdlist)
     {
       <tr id="@itms.TAKEOVER_D_id">
          <td class="text-left">
          <input type="hidden" name="tasklist[]" id="task_id" value="@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_id)" />
          </td>

          <td class="text-left">
          <input type="text" id="task@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_id)" name="task@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_id)" value="@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_task)" style="width:100%" />                                            
          </td>

          <td class="text-left">
          <input type="text" id="amnt@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_id)" name="amnt@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_id)" value="@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_amount)" style="width:100%" />                                            
          </td>

          <td class="text-left">
          <input type="checkbox" id="donebit@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_id)" name="donebit@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_id)" value="@(itms.TAKEOVER_D_done)" style="width:100%" />                                            
          </td>

       </tr>
  }
```

I get other values just fine, but the checkbox is unchecked. It should be checked.

When I inspect the table the value for the checkbox is "value".

Comment: You need to use `Html.CheckBox` else you need to set condition-wise `checked` attribute.

Comment: what kind of value available in `TAKEOVER_D_done`. Like every checkbox must be checked or specific value-wise?

Comment: TAKEOVER_D_done takes bit value. It is specific. Some are checked and some are not